# Breaking Swagger JSON based on the modules using NODEJS

Tags: node.js, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I have 3 modules of A,B,C and 10 api calls in each module.I want modularize my api-docs.json based on the modules . So, each module has it's own api-docs.json. Is it possible in Swagger 2.0 ?

Comment: Check my below answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can group wise set it with "{tag}" name, and yes, you can call all API which is module wise.

Thanks,